# Applying more current?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

An electric motor draws 20 Amps, when at maximum load of x.
Can that value of current be applied even if the load was ten times less than x from a certain power source?

Answer (score 1):

If your motor is spinning at an angular velocity $\omega$ and applying a torque $T$ then the power the motor is generating is $P = T\omega$ and this is related to the input power $VI$ by:

$$ VI = T\omega + F(\omega, ...) $$

where $F$ is the power lost to friction and resistance - note that $F$ will be dependant on the angular velocity (and probably other factors too). If the load is ten times less then that means the torque becomes $T/10$. If friction stayed constant then you could keep the input power the same by increasing the angular velocity to $10\omega$. In practice $F$ will increase as $\omega$ increases so you wouldn't need to increase $\omega$ as much.

Comment: However, in order for me to increase the angular velocity by 10 times, I would feed the motor more input? Basically, can I force a circuit more current than what it needs?

Comment: An ideal motor would increase in speed as you reduced the lod. For a real motor you would need to increase the voltage to push more current through the motor. Whether you could keep the current constant depends on whether the motor would burn out at the increased voltage.